# Properly managing cursor when using AlertDialog with setCursor

Tags: android, cursor, android-alertdialog

Consider following code:

```
private View.OnClickListener mTemplateButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewMailActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.str_new_mail_activity_choose_template));

            final Cursor c = MailData.getTemplateCursor();

            builder.setCursor(c, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
                {
                    c.moveToPosition(item);
                    et_body.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MailData.TEMPLATES_TABLE_COL_BODY)));
                    et_subject.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MailData.TEMPLATES_TABLE_COL_SUBJECT)));
                }
            }, MailData.TEMPLATES_TABLE_COL_SUBJECT);

            templatesAlertDialog = builder.create();
            templatesAlertDialog.show();
        }
    };
```

I use it to bring up list of templates in AlertDialog.

Cursor with data loaded using `MailData.getTemplateCursor()` It queries SQLite database for data. I can't figure out proper place where to close cursor, because if I do it - I don't get any data.

Is there any way to populate AlertDialog with ArrayList for example?

EDIT: I found one solution using ListAdapter, but it requires layout, etc and makes it unnecessary complex. Any other solution?

Comment: what about dismiss listener?

Comment: How do I add dismiss listener?

Comment: setOnDismissListener?